# C programming in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Do you know if it's possible to programm c (not c++) in Visual Studio 2008? If yes then how? I haven't found any component for that.

Regards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just save the file with .c extension instead of .cpp and it will compile as C instead of C++. To be extra cautious, you can go to the project settings, under "Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced", make sure that "Compile As" says "Compile as C code (/TC)".

Answer (score 6):

As long as your source file has the `.c` extension, Microsoft C++ compiler will compile in C-mode.

In addition, the `/Tc<source filename>` switch can be used to force compilation of a specific file in C mode, and the `/TC` switch can be used to force C mode for all files. For C++, it's `/Tp` and `/TP` respectively.

Comment: Do I get an exeption if my programm has some c++ code in this way?

Comment: You should do. It's a while since I programmed in C though

Comment: yes, any C++ constructs present in files that are being compiled in C mode will fail to compile

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any compiler you'd like in VisualStudio; therefore, if there's a specific C compiler you'd like to use, it will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a .c program in Visual Studio 2008:

> Goto>>File>>New>>Project

Choose "Visual C++" in the left column, then in the right column, select "Win 32 Console Application".

Write file name as:

> "Any_Name.c"

Here you can now create a C program:

- Create source file
- To compile, press ctrl+shift+B
- To run, press F5

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because C++ precompiled headers, so the solution is select project-properties-c/c++-precompiled headers 
Then select Not Using Precompiled Headers